# no me muestra ciertos valores al ejecutar el print de una clase

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Vehiculo:
    color = ""
    ruedas = 0
    
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas 
        
    def __str__(self):
        return """ 
        color: {}
        ruedas: {}""".format(self.color, self.ruedas)

class coche(Vehiculo):
    velocidad = 0
    cilindrada = 0
    
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada):
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
    
    def __str__(self):
        return """ 
        color: {}
        ruedas: {}
        velocidad: {}
        cilindrada: {}
        """.format(self.color, self.ruedas, self.velocidad, self.cilindrada)
    

renault = coche("verde", 4, 120, 14)
print(renault)
```

Al imprimir por pantalla no me muestra el string `verde`, y donde debería ir número de ruedas que es `4` me sale `0`, no se que he hecho mal

Comment: `color`, `ruedas` y `velocidad`, `cilindrada` en esta lógica no deberían ser declaradas como atributos de clase o variables de clase. Estas se dejan para valores que van a ser constantes entre todos los objetos. Si eliminas esas variables debajo de `class`, y con las correcciones que han propuesto, el programa va a seguir funcionando igual.

Answer (score 5):

Bienvenido a SO es Liam c:

## Explicación

Tu problema se debe a que en ningún momento le das un valor al color del auto y la cantidad de ruedas. Como no tiene un valor, Python lo busca en la clase padre y encuentra los valores en estas lineas:

```
class Vehiculo:
    color = ""
    ruedas = 0
```

Que como verás coincide con los datos "erroneos" que te muestra.

Supongo que esto se debe a que asumes que la función `__init__` de Vehiculo se ejecuta también en Coche. Cosa que en tu caso no es cierta.

## Solución

```
class coche(Vehiculo):
    velocidad = 0
    cilindrada = 0

    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada):
        # llamo a la función __init__ de vehiculo y le paso de argumentos el color y la cantidad de ruedas
        super().__init__(self, color, ruedas) 
        
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
```

## Bonus: Como funciona un método de clase.

Un metodo es una función que está asociada a una clase. Algunos de estos metodos son llamados por Python internamente, como `__init__` y `__str__`.
Cuando Python busca atributos y métodos en clases derivadas, primero busca en la clase derivada y luego en la clase padre. Si lo encuentra, deja de buscar.

Te doy un ejemplo:

```
class clase_padre:
    def __init__(Self):
        print("init de clase padre")

class clase_derivada(clase_padre):
    def __init__(Self):
        print("init de clase derivada")

print(clase_padre())
print(clase_derivada())
```

Esto produce en consola:

```
init de clase padre
init de clase derivada
```

Como habrás visto, el init de `clase_padre` no se ejecutó cuando llamé a `clase_derivada`.
Esto se debe a lo antes explicado. Esto hace que `__init__` de clase_padre sea reemplazado por el `__init__` de clase_derivada.

Ahora, observa que pasa si quitamos el `__init__` en clase_derivada.

```
class clase_padre:
    def __init__(Self):
        print("clase padre")

class clase_derivada(clase_padre):
    pass

print(clase_padre())
print(clase_derivada())
```

Esto produce en consola:

```
init de clase padre
init de clase padre
```

Por que pasó esto? Por que clase_derivada no tenía un metodo llamado `__init__`, por lo que tomó el método `__init__` de la clase padre.

Esto mismo aplica también a los atributos. En tu caso color y ruedas son atributos de clase.

Aquí hay info de como funciona una clase: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-smooth-refresher-on-pythons-classes-and-objects--cms-25598

Y aquí de como funciona una clase derivada https://www.codigofuente.org/herencia-en-python/

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta, Dante! Solo un par de acotaciones en aras de dejar todo claro. 1. Cuando una clase `A` hereda de `B`, se copian en `B` todos los miembros de `A`. O sea, está mal decir que "clase_derivada no tenía un método llamado `__init__`". Por supuesto que sí lo tiene, solo que no lo está sobreescribiendo. Puedes comprobar esto haciendo `dir(clase_derivada)` y verás que allí está `__init__`, además de todos los miembros de `clase_padre`.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion @revliscano!

Answer (score 0):

Es porque no guarda los valores en **init** de la clase coche.  Debe llamar a super(), como:

```
def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada):
    self.velocidad = velocidad
    self.cilindrada = cilindrada
    super().__init__(self, color, ruedas)
```

Answer (score 0):

Es porque esta mal escrito el código en python las clases no defines con variable, me funciono de la siguiente manera.

```
    class Vehiculo:

    def __init__(self, color, ruedas):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas 
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "color: {},ruedas: {}".format(self.color, self.ruedas)

class coche(Vehiculo):

    
    def __init__(self, color, ruedas, velocidad, cilindrada):
        self.color = color
        self.ruedas = ruedas
        self.velocidad = velocidad
        self.cilindrada = cilindrada
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "color: {}, ruedas: {},velocidad: {},cilindrada: {}".format(self.color, self.ruedas, self.velocidad, self.cilindrada)
    

renault = coche("verde", 4, 120, 14)
print(renault)
```